# Python catch a custom exception

Tags: python

I am using a module named dbfread in python 3.4 and it raises an exception - "DbfError". How can I catch it?

I cannot find where this error is defined and thus cannot import it.

Comment: You know the package name, though. What package is it?  Have you looked at its help or done a `dir` to see if there are exceptions defined in it? Then you could look at the directory in `packagename.__path__` or `packagename.__file__` and search the source.

Comment: Just found it, Its in from dbf.ver_33 import DbfError. The docs did not have the errors defined.

Comment: Looking at the source from pypi, it appears that it is also at `dbf.DbfError`. This location would likely be the better choice in case the implementation module changes. `ver_33` makes me wonder if there is a `ver_34` somewhere in the future.

Comment: I see it as well now, but I can't import it (from dbf import DbfError), as my IDE shows that this class does not exist. Maybe it's me being a noob.

Comment: OK, so just did `getattr(dbf, 'DbfError')` and got the following <class 'dbf.ver_33.DbfError'>. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, this `dbf` module is weird. It has different modules for different versions of python, so that `ver_33` is for python 3.3. Stay away from that!  Then, way of importing from 33 is just bizarre. It puts fake values into its `__all__` then does an scan of `ver_33` to bring in its name. That's what confuses your IDE. I bet if you use `dbf.DbfError` it will work fine even if the IDE goes nuts.

Comment: Cheers! Do you want to reply as an answer, so that I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting the [`dbf` module source](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf), it has different submodules for different versions of python and `DbfError` is defined in those submodules. It conditionally imports `DbfError` from the version-specific module using a `for` loop. That seems like an odd way to do things and it appears to have confused your IDE.

But you should use `dbf.DbfError` so that your code works on multiple python versions.